# Posting input from one page to an external web service and then rendering back resultant XML

Tags: xslt, umbraco

I am new to Umbraco (v 4.5.2) and would like know how I could do the following:

1. A visitor on a page types in to a
   text box a domain name.
2. They hit
   return or clicks on an image button
3. I want Umbraco to post that domain
   name to a aspx page that I will
   write on another site.
4. This
   handler will then return some XML
   that I want Umbraco to render via
   XSLT.

I am competent in c# and dotNet but before I dive in and write a load of code I was wondering of there is an existing easier way to do this?

Many thanks in advance

Jonathan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand the problem you want to develop a web page that sends a request to a page on another site, get a bunch of XML back and renders this XML into nice HTML on the page you're making the request from.

When writing xslt in Umbraco you have access to the umbraco.library extension methods, and one of those methods is GetXmlDocumentByUrl(string Url), that enables fetching external xml docs and work with them in xslt.

So I would create a page has a small form that uses GET to query for the domain name, and then handle the rest in xslt

Your code would look something like:

```
<xsl:variable name="domainName" value="umbraco.library:RequestQueryString('domain')" />
<xsl:variable name="resultDoc" value=umbraco.library:GetXmlDocumentByUrl(concat('http://domain.net/path/to/query?domain=', $domainName))" />
<xsl:apply-templates match="/">
<!-- XSLT that iterates over $resultDoc/result or something like that -->
</xsl:apply-templates>
```

Regards
Jesper Hauge

P.S. For loads of information, and quicker response be sure to check out http://our.umbraco.org, where you will find a very lively and friendly forum for questions like these.